# Editor template for creating radio button for enum fields not working for all enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, mvc-editor-templates

I have this editor template with name `RadioButtonQuestion`

```
@model Enum

@{
    // Looks for a [Display(Name="Some Name")] or a [Display(Name="Some Name", ResourceType=typeof(ResourceFile)] Attribute on your enum
    Func<Enum, string> getDescription = en =>
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {

            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute),
                                                            false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
        }

        return en.ToString();
    };
    var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
    new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = getDescription(e),
        Value = e.ToString(),
        Selected = e.Equals(Model)
    });
    string prefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    int index = 0;
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Empty;

    foreach (var li in listItems)
    {
        string fieldName = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}_{1}", prefix, index++);
        <div class="editor-radio">
            @Html.RadioButton(prefix, li.Value, li.Selected, new { @id = fieldName })
            @Html.Label(fieldName, li.Text)
        </div>
    }
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;
}
```

For the following model

```
public class CreateAppointmentSelectOptions
{      
    public QuestionStart StartQuestion { get; set; }

    public QuestionEnd EndQuestion { get; set; }   
}

public enum QuestionStart
{
    [Display(Name="Repeat till common match is found")]
    RepeatTillCommonIsFound,

    [Display(Name="Repeat once")]
    RepeatOnce,    

    [Display(Name="No repeat")]
    NoRepeat

}

public enum QuestionEnd
{
    [Display(Name="Cancel Invitation")]
    CancelInvitation,

    [Display(Name="Plan with participants on first available common date")]
    FirstAvailableCommon,

    [Display(Name="Plan with participants on my first available common date")]
    YourFirstAvailableCommon
}
```

with following view

```
@model InfoBridgeSmartDatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Appointment.CreateAppointmentSelectOptions
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create_WhatIf";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create_WhatIf", "Appointment", FormMethod.Post))
{      
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartQuestion, "RadioButtonQuestion") &nbsp; &nbsp;
                </div>               

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">         
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndQuestion, "RadioButtonQuestion")&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </div>                             

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

the editortemplate works perfectly, it creates radiobuttons for each field of enum, but for following 
model

```
public class AttendeeResponse
{
    public IsAttending Isattending { get; set; }      
}

public enum IsAttending
{
    [Display(Name="Attending")]
    Attending,

    [Display(Name="Not attending")]
    NotAttending
}
```

with following view

```
@model InfoBridgeSmartDatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Response.AttendeeResponse
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}  
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Response",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Isattending, "RadioButtonQuestion") &nbsp; &nbsp;
                </div>               

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div id="provideDateTime">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Response/_AttendeeAvailableDateTime.cshtml");}
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

i get error on this line of editor template

```
     return en.ToString();
Line 21:     };
/*error on this line Line*/ 22:     var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
Line 23:     new SelectListItem()
Line 24:     {
```

any idea why this editor template is not working for second view?

**StackTrace:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_EditorTemplates_RadioButtonQuestion_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\userx\Desktop\Git\DatePickerApp\datepicker\DatePicker\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\RadioButtonQuestion.cshtml:22
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +120
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +145
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +1037
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1633
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +140
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName) +94
   ASP._Page_Views_Response_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\userx\Desktop\Git\DatePickerApp\datepicker\DatePicker\Views\Response\Index.cshtml:14
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +120
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +63
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +100
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +131
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

PS: I got this editor template from [this github project](https://gist.github.com/ThumNet/1010654)

Comment: Are you sure that's the same code you are using? It is working fine for me. However I get that error on the same line if I declare my property as Nullable: `public IsAttending? Isattending { get; set; }` and it is null in the model passed to the view

Comment: I found the problem, it was because from my conrtoller i wasn't passing the instance of view's model class. Now i instantiated object of my class and sent it to model, then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Glad to see you already found the solution.

However you could make the editor template more robust, so it doesn't break if a null model is passed to the view and also it is compatible with nullable types like `IsAttending?`

Just change this code to get the enum values:

```
var listItems = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = getDescription(e),
    Value = e.ToString(),
    Selected = e.Equals(Model)
});
```

With this code that doesn't depend on the current model instance:

```
var enumType = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;
if (enumType.IsGenericType && enumType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
}

var listItems = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = getDescription(e),
    Value = e.ToString(),
    Selected = e.Equals(Model)
});
```

**EDIT - Code used to with the Nullable enum type and null model passed to the view scenarios**

Model

```
public class AttendeeResponse
{
    public IsAttending? Isattending { get; set; }
}

public enum IsAttending
{
    [Display(Name = "Attending")]
    Attending,

    [Display(Name = "Not attending")]
    NotAttending
}
```

View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.AttendeeResponse

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Attendee Response";
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Response",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Isattending, "RadioButtonQuestion") &nbsp; &nbsp;
                </div>               

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Editor Template

```
@model Enum

@{
    // Looks for a [Display(Name="Some Name")] or a [Display(Name="Some Name", ResourceType=typeof(ResourceFile)] Attribute on your enum
    Func<Enum, string> getDescription = en =>
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {

            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute),
                                                            false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
        }

        return en.ToString();
    };

    var enumType = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;
    if (enumType.IsGenericType && enumType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
    }

    var listItems = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
    new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = getDescription(e),
        Value = e.ToString(),
        Selected = e.Equals(Model)
    });
    string prefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    int index = 0;
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Empty;

    foreach (var li in listItems)
    {
        string fieldName = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}_{1}", prefix, index++);
        <div class="editor-radio">
            @Html.RadioButton(prefix, li.Value, li.Selected, new { @id = fieldName })
            @Html.Label(fieldName, li.Text)
        </div>
    }
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Attendee()
{
    //You can pass null as the view model and the view/editor template won't break
    return View();
    //This would also work, showing that you can have a nullable with null value
    //return View(new AttendeeResponse());
    //If the nullable enum has a value, it would appear as selected:
    //return View(new AttendeeResponse{Isattending = IsAttending.NotAttending});
}
```

Comment: but would it work if i had done the mistake that i did, without passing the object to view from controller? Just  tried but it didn't work. Also, we are mentioning it can be nullable, but from the front end, by default we will have a radion button selected and I think we will end up selecting one radion button at least. Sorry if i'm wrong. But i like the approach. +1 for that

Comment: If you use a nullable property, no value would be selected by default (as it is a nullable). That would allow scenarios where the field is mandatory or to force the user selecting a value themselves. I also tried that code with a null model passed into the view and it worked, will update with the exact code that I used

Comment: By the way, I am not saying you should pass a null model into the view, or that you should define your enum property as nullable. It's just that updating the editor template this way would support these scenarios, making it more flexible/robust :)

Comment: oh ok. Learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I hadn't passed the object(the model that view is using) via the controller's get method. Once i did that it worked.

Previously I had

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {

    return View();
 }
```

once i did

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    var attendeeresponse = new AttendeeResponse();
    return View(attendeeresponse);
 }
```

it worked